# When I create a webpage within IIS (Windows Server) and I get asked to specify the "physical path" ,do I need to

Tags: iis, deployment, web

specify a folder within the "inetpub/wwwroot" folder or maybe I can specify a folder that is located in my desktop?

In my setup it seems like I can only specify a folder that is within the inetpub folder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical path can be anywhere on your server that you specify. It does not need to be under inetpub. However, inetpub has some default permissions configured on it which are beneficial to you hosting websites there.